# Linq Intersect with arrays

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Im getting a table Tags from the db.

the table has columns ID and TagName

I'm doing something like this to get a list of strings:

```
var taglist = Model.Tags.Select(x => x.TagName.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

then I'm comparing against another string array to get the strings that occur in both:

```
var intersectList = tagList.Intersect(anotherList);
```

I have my list, but now I also want the ID of each item remaining in the intersect list that corresponds to the tagList. (can just be an int array)

Can anyone help with a good way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use intersect, it only works for collections of the same type.  You could do a simple join or other form of filtering.  It would be easiest to throw the string list into a `HashSet` and filter by tags that contain `TagName`s in that set.  This way, you keep your tags unprojected so they keep their ids and other properties.

```
var stringSet = anotherList.ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var tagList = Model.Tags.Where(t => stringSet.Contains(t.TagName)).ToList();
```

And put them into a list.  Don't throw them into an array unless you specifically need an array (for use in a method that expects an array).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `Dictionary<int, string>` instead of `Array`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
var intersectIds = Model.Tags
    .Where(tag => anotherList.Contains(tag.TagName))
    .Select(tag => tag.Id)
    .ToList();
```